# How to do Flutter grid style column ? not 1 row

Tags: flutter, dart

I have flutter controller name categories and showing my categories items all of them 1 (row) line with scrolling like under below;

```
 BOX BOX BOX BOX BOX BOX BOX BOX BOX BOX BOX BOX BOX BOX BOX ..... ...
```

I want under below like full with in device 3-4 max column and another ones add inside rows;

```
  BOX BOX BOX BOX
  BOX BOX BOX BOX
  BOX BOX BOX BOX
  BOX BOX BOX BOX
  BOX BOX BOX BOX
  BOX BOX BOX BOX
  ... ...
```

My codes under below how can I fix this ?

```
class Categories extends StatelessWidget {
  double marginLeft;
  Category category;
  Categories({Key key, this.marginLeft, this.category}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      splashColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor.withOpacity(0.08),
      highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/Categories', arguments: RouteArgument(id: category.id));
      },
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Hero(
            tag: category.id,
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: this.marginLeft, end: 20),
              width: 80,
              height: 80,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
                  boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: Theme.of(context).focusColor.withOpacity(0.2), offset: Offset(0, 2), blurRadius: 7.0)]),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                child: category.image.url.toLowerCase().endsWith('.svg')
                    ? SvgPicture.network(
                        category.image.url,
                        color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                      )
                    : CachedNetworkImage(
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        imageUrl: category.image.icon,
                        placeholder: (context, url) => Image.asset(
                          'assets/img/loading.gif',
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                        errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
                      ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 5),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: this.marginLeft, end: 20),
            child: Text(
              category.name,
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Category model;

```
class Category {
  String id;
  String name;
  Media image;

  Category();

  Category.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap) {
    try {
      id = jsonMap['id'].toString();
      name = jsonMap['name'];
      image = jsonMap['media'] != null && (jsonMap['media'] as List).length > 0 ? Media.fromJSON(jsonMap['media'][0]) : new Media();
    } catch (e) {
      id = '';
      name = '';
      image = new Media();
      print(CustomTrace(StackTrace.current, message: e));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the widget `GridView`:

```
//An example list to represent your categories 
final List<Category> categories = [
  Category(id: '1', name: 'categoryName', image: yourFirstImage),
  Category(id: '2', name: 'anotherName', image: yourSecondImage),
];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: 4, //number of childs in each row
      mainAxisSpacing: 2, //horizontal space between childs
      crossAxisSpacing: 2, //vertical space between childs
      children: List.generate(
        categories.length, //the number of categories inside the list
        (index) {
          return Categories(  //your widget here
            category: categories[index],
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: ty man but im new in flutter how can implement this into my codes ? can you please put this inside ?

Comment: Yes i can, but just to clarify, is this Categories widget the model for each Category that you want to display? If it is, just change the Container in my example with your **Categories**, and change the **40** in the List.generate to the length of your categories.

Comment: yes this codes working in my project when I built, can you add this codes inside my codes after I will build it and we will show :) thank you

Comment: gives errors also I added my category model updated answer , I placed your codes gives many error :(

Comment: It was just an example of how you can implement the GridView, what errors occurred?

Comment: Oh i see, your Category class have a named and an empty constructor, for my example to work you must add a constructor that receives the id, name and image, or adapt it for your named constructor.